# How to replace occurrences of multiple strings with multiple other strings [NSString]

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsstring

```
NSString *string  = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<wow>" withString:someString];
```

I have this code. Now suppose my app's user enters two different strings I want to replace with two different other strings, how do I achieve that? I don't care if it uses private APIs, i'm developing for the jailbroken platform. My user is going to either enter  or  or . I want to replace any occurrences of those strings with their respective to-be-replaced-with strings :)

Thanks in advance :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both dasblinkenlight’s and Matthias’s answers will work, but they both result in the creation of a couple of intermediate NSStrings; that’s not really a problem if you’re not doing this operation often, but a better approach would look like this.

```
NSMutableString *myStringMut = [[myString mutableCopy] autorelease];
[myStringMut replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"a" withString:somethingElse];
[myStringMut replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"b" withString:somethingElseElse];
// etc.
```

You can then use `myStringMut` as you would’ve used `myString`, since NSMutableString is an NSString subclass.

Comment: Thank you, oh great almighty saver :P No I really mean it, thanks a lot :)

Comment: One thing to watch out for is that if somethingElse contains "b"s, they will be replaced with somethingElseElse. Sometimes this is ok but sometimes it isn't. A more sophisticated approach is needed if you need to avoid that situation.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest solution is running `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` twice:

```
NSString *string  = [[myString
    stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<wow>" withString:someString1]
    stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<boo>" withString:someString2];
```

Comment: :-)  **Excellent ..looks more smooth in swift interface** -                                 `let string = myString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("<wow>", withString: someString1).stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("<boo>", withString: someString2)`

Answer (score 2):

I would just run the string replacing method again

```
NSString *string  = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"foo" withString:@"String 1"];
string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"bar" withString:@"String 2"];
```

Comment: I thought of that but then when I tested it out I felt I should really consider asking proffesionals like you awesome guys. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

This works well for me in Swift 3.1

```
let str = "hi hello hey"

var replacedStr = (str as NSString).replacingOccurrences(of: "hi", with: "Hi")

replacedStr = (replacedStr as NSString).replacingOccurrences(of: "hello", with: "Hello")

replacedStr = (replacedStr as NSString).replacingOccurrences(of: "hey", with: "Hey")

print(replacedStr) // Hi Hello Hey
```